# RVM/Rails installation error on ubuntu 11.04

Tags: ruby-on-rails

After upgrading to ubuntu 11.04 I am having this problem with rvm.
I am following this tutorial:
http://ruby.railstutorial.org/ruby-on-rails-tutorial-book#top

Git is installed OK, when I follow the instructions on RVM website apparently it's OK too, but when I close my terminal and open a new one and type `ruby -v` or `rvm -v` for example I got a message "rvm is not installed".

What should I do?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After some Googling I found:
http://ygamretuta.me/2011/05/09/install-rvm-in-ubuntu-11-04-and-mac-osx-snow-leopard/

which worked for me (Ubuntu 11.04, x64)

Edit your .bashrc file instead of your ~/.bash_profile file with your favorite editor

`vim .bashrc`

add this to the bottom:

`if [[ -s "$HOME/.rvm/scripts/rvm" ]]  ; then source "$HOME/.rvm/scripts/rvm" ; fi`

Hope this helps guys!

Answer (score 2):

Check do you have ~/.bash_profile and add next code in it (create file if it does not exists):

```
[[ -s "$HOME/.rvm/scripts/rvm" ]] && source "$HOME/.rvm/scripts/rvm" # Load RVM into a shell session *as a function*
```

Also, if you use gnu screen you should add

```
source ~/.bash_profile
```

to the end of your ~/.bashrc file.

Then type

```
type rvm | head -1
```

in your terminal and you should get message "**rvm is a function**"

After that you would be able to follow instructions on [RailsTutorial](http://ruby.railstutorial.org/ruby-on-rails-tutorial-book#sec%3arubygems).

Answer (score 1):

I recently wrote up a tutorial on getting RVM up and running on Ubuntu 11.04: http://blog.dcxn.com/2011/06/20/setting-up-rvm-on-ubuntu-11-04/

Hopefully it helps if you have future problems or if there are still questions.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem and will list the steps that worked for me:

1. Following [this article](http://www.christopherirish.com/2010/08/25/how-to-install-rvm-on-ubuntu-10-04/) was very helpful (even if I have 11.04 installed)
2. The installation was performed with `sudo` privileges
3. The installation didn't added `/usr/local/rvm/bin` to `PATH`

Hope this helps to someone