# Using Hudson and Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, hudson, rake, rakefile

I'm trying to use the rails plugin with hudson, but i'm getting the following error, and I have no idea how to do this, follow the stack:

```
Updating URL revision: Jan 18, 2012 1:01:56 PM depth:infinity ignoreExternals: false
At revision 21
no change for URL since the previous build
[workspace] $ /bin/sh -xe /etc/tomcat6/apache-tomcat-6.0.35/temp/hudson9010951436400252341.sh
+ cd Hermodr
+ cd trunk
+ bundle install
Using rake (0.9.2.2) 
Using multi_json (1.0.4) 
Using activesupport (3.1.1) 
Using builder (3.0.0) 
Using i18n (0.6.0) 
Using activemodel (3.1.1) 
Using erubis (2.7.0) 
Using rack (1.3.6) 
Using rack-cache (1.1) 
Using rack-mount (0.8.3) 
Using rack-test (0.6.1) 
Using hike (1.2.1) 
Using tilt (1.3.3) 
Using sprockets (2.0.3) 
Using actionpack (3.1.1) 
Using mime-types (1.17.2) 
Using polyglot (0.3.3) 
Using treetop (1.4.10) 
Using mail (2.3.0) 
Using actionmailer (3.1.1) 
Using arel (2.2.1) 
Using tzinfo (0.3.31) 
Using activerecord (3.1.1) 
Using activeresource (3.1.1) 
Using ansi (1.4.1) 
Using bundler (1.0.21) 
Using coffee-script-source (1.2.0) 
Using execjs (1.2.13) 
Using coffee-script (2.2.0) 
Using rack-ssl (1.3.2) 
Using json (1.6.5) 
Using rdoc (3.12) 
Using thor (0.14.6) 
Using railties (3.1.1) 
Using coffee-rails (3.1.1) 
Using jquery-rails (1.0.19) 
Using minitest (2.10.1) 
Using rails (3.1.1) 
Using sass (3.1.12) 
Using sass-rails (3.1.5) 
Using sqlite3 (1.3.5) 
Using turn (0.8.3) 
Using uglifier (1.2.2) 
[32mYour bundle is complete! Use `bundle show [gemname]` to see where a bundled gem is installed.[0m
+ rake db:migrate
rake aborted!
/home/hp/.hudson/jobs/SVN/workspace/Hermodr/trunk/config/initializers/session_store.rb:3: syntax error, unexpected ':', expecting $end
...sion_store :cookie_store, key: '_Hermodr_session'
                              ^

Tasks: TOP => db:migrate => environment
(See full trace by running task with --trace)
[DEBUG] Skipping watched dependency update for build: SVN #8 due to result: FAILURE
Finished: FAILURE
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like you're using an pre-1.9 version of Ruby with Hudson - it's expecting the `:symbol => value` syntax instead of the newer`symbol: value`.

You'll either need to update the version of Ruby on the build machine or install RVM to manage rubies for the user Hudson is running under.

Comment: Ok, I'm at ubuntu 11.04, and i trying to install the RVM, but it doesn't works, I've tried to follow these tutorials:
http://beginrescueend.com/rvm/install/ |
http://www.web2linux.com/05/installing-rails-3-on-ubuntu-10-04-lucid-lynx/ |
http://ryanbigg.com/2010/12/ubuntu-ruby-rvm-rails-and-you/

Comment: possibly this? - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5967027/problem-on-rvm-rails-instalation-ubuntu-11-04